# Окно с QCheckBox

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qmessagebox, qcheckbox

Имеется окно с `QCheckBox` (**chech.py**). По умолчанию выставлены три галки `checkbox` (**`п.1`**, **`п2`**, **`п3`**) и четвертая галка `checkbox` ("Выбрать все папки") – пока первые три `checkbox` имеют статус `True`. Если снять одну из трех галок `checkbox` (п.1, п2, п3), то четвертая галка `checkbox` ("Выбрать все папки") – снимается (**скриншот №1**).

*Трудности*: Но если снять четвертую галку `checkbox` ("Выбрать все папки") – первые три галки `checkbox` (**`п.1`**, **`п2`**, **`п3`**) остаются (**скриншот №2**).

*Вопрос*: Как сделать, что бы при  снятии четвертой галки `checkbox` ("Выбрать все папки") – первые три галки `checkbox` (**`п.1`**, **`п2`**, **`п3`**) тоже снимались.

P.S. предложения по улучшению кода приветствуются.

---

**1.** [image: введите сюда описание изображения] **2.** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**chech.py**

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QCheckBox, QMessageBox, )
from PyQt5.QtCore import (pyqtSlot, )

class MessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox, QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Внимание!")
        self.setIcon(self.Critical)
        self.addButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Удалить'), QtWidgets.QMessageBox.YesRole)
        self.addButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Отмена'), QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoRole)
        self.addCheckBox(self)

        currentClick = self.exec_()
        if currentClick == 0:
            print(' нажата кнопка = Удалить')
            print()

            if self.check1.isChecked() == False and \
               self.check2.isChecked() == False and \
               self.check3.isChecked() == False:
               self.not_del()
            else:
                if self.check1.isChecked() == True:
                    print(' значение CheckBox (1. ) =', self.check1.isChecked())
                    self.del_Doc()

                if self.check2.isChecked() == True:
                    print(' значение CheckBox (2. ) =', self.check2.isChecked())
                    self.del_Otv()

                if self.check3.isChecked() == True:
                    print(' значение CheckBox (3. ) =', self.check3.isChecked())
                    self.del_Im()
            self.message()
        if currentClick == 1:
            print(' нажата кнопка = Отмена')

    def addCheckBox(self, parentItem):
        self.l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lb1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Файлы удалятся безвозвратно. \n              Вы уверены?", self)
        lb1.setGeometry(60, 15, 300, 40)
        lb2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Следующие данные будут удалены:', self)
        lb2.setGeometry(20, 60, 350, 20)

        self._toggle = True
        self.check1 = QCheckBox('1.', self)
        self.check1.setGeometry(20, 85, 200, 20)
        self.check1.setChecked(self._toggle)

        self.check2 = QCheckBox('2.', self)
        self.check2.setGeometry(20, 105, 200, 20)
        self.check2.setChecked(self._toggle)

        self.check3 = QCheckBox('3.', self)
        self.check3.setGeometry(20, 125, 200, 20)
        self.check3.setChecked(self._toggle)

        self.check = QCheckBox('Выбрать все папки', self)
        self.check.setGeometry(20, 155, 200, 20)
        self.check.setChecked(self._toggle)

        self.check1.clicked.connect(self.chec_toggle)
        self.check2.clicked.connect(self.chec_toggle)
        self.check3.clicked.connect(self.chec_toggle)
        self.check.clicked.connect(self.chec_toggle)
        self.setLayout(self.l)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def chec_toggle(self):
        if self.sender() == self.check:
            if self._toggle == True:
                self.check1.setChecked(self._toggle)
                self.check2.setChecked(self._toggle)
                self.check3.setChecked(self._toggle)
            else:
                self.check1.setChecked(not self._toggle)
                self.check2.setChecked(not self._toggle)
                self.check3.setChecked(not self._toggle)
                self.check.setChecked(not self._toggle)

        elif self.sender() in (self.check1, self.check2, self.check3):
            self.check.setChecked(not self._toggle)

    def del_Doc(self): pass
    def del_Otv(self): pass
    def del_Im(self): pass

    def not_del(self):
        msgBox = QMessageBox(self)
        msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle('Внимание!')
        msgBox.setText("   Ни одна папка не выбрана!   ")
        msgBox.exec_()

    def message(self):
        msgBox0 = QMessageBox(self)
        msgBox0.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msgBox0.setText('Операция очистки завершена.  ')
        msgBox0.exec_()

    def event(self, e):
        result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.event(self, e)
        self.setMinimumWidth(0)
        self.setMaximumWidth(16777215)
        self.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.setMaximumHeight(16777215)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )
        self.resize(250, 230)
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MessageBox()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, мне тяжело помочь вам с вашим кодом. Возможное решение может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Custom_QGroupBox(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):
    checkAllIfAny = True
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Custom_QGroupBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.checkBoxes = []
        self.toggled.connect(self.toggleCheckBoxes)

    def addCheckBox(self, cb):
        self.checkBoxes.append(cb)
        cb.toggled.connect(self.update)
        cb.destroyed.connect(lambda: self.removeCheckBox(cb))

    def removeCheckBox(self, cb):
        try:
            self.checkBoxes.remove(cb)
            cb.toggled.disconnect(self.update)
        except:
            pass

    def allStates(self):
        return [cb.isChecked() for cb in self.checkBoxes]

    def toggleCheckBoxes(self):
        if self.checkAllIfAny:
            state = not all(self.allStates())
        else:
            state = not any(self.allStates())

        for widget in self.children():
            if not widget.isWidgetType():
                continue
            if not widget.testAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_ForceDisabled):
                # восстановить включенное состояние, чтобы переопределить 
                # поведение setChecked(False) по умолчанию; 
                # предыдущие явные вызовы setEnabled(False) для целевого виджета 
                # будут игнорироваться
                widget.setEnabled(True)
                if widget in self.checkBoxes:
                    widget.setChecked(state)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionGroupBox()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        states = self.allStates()
        if all(states):
            # force the "checked" state
            opt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_On
            opt.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Off
        else:
            # force the "not checked" state
            opt.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_On
            if any(states):
                # force the "not unchecked" state and set the tristate mode
                opt.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Off
                opt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_NoChange
            else:
                # force the "unchecked" state
                opt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Off
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        painter.drawComplexControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_GroupBox, opt)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.groupBox = Custom_QGroupBox('Все папки')
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        num = 0
        for c in range(1):
            for r in range(3):
                num += 1
                cb = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(f' {num}.')
                self.groupBox.addCheckBox(cb)
                layout.addWidget(cb, r, c)

        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.toolButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('head3.png'))
        self.toolButton.setAutoRaise(True)
        self.toolButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 70))
        self.toolButton.setStyleSheet(
            'background-color: green; border-radius: 35px;')
            
        label_1 = QLabel("Файлы удалятся безвозвратно. Вы уверены?")
        label_1.setWordWrap(True)
        label_2 = QLabel('Следующие данные будут удалены:')
        
        self.buttonDelete = QPushButton('Удалить')
        self.buttonCancel = QPushButton('Отмена')
        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addStretch(1)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.buttonDelete)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.buttonCancel)

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.toolButton, 1, 1)
        main_layout.addWidget(label_1, 1, 2)
        main_layout.addWidget(label_2, 2, 1, 1, 2)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 3, 1, 1, 2)
        main_layout.addLayout(layoutH, 4, 1, 1, 2)
        
        main_layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        main_layout.setRowStretch(5, 1)
        main_layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        main_layout.setColumnStretch(3, 1)
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(370, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересная идея, до этого такого примера на глаза не попадалось, но к сожалению, не совсем то что ожидалось. Трудно Вам наверное приходится с теми, кто хочет чего то  конкретного, подчас нереализуемого.

Comment: Скажите, а в Вашем скрипте, когда мышь перемещается в зоне `groupBox`, непрерывно задействованы  `def allStates` и `def paintEvent`, не повлияет ли это на загрузку процессора / Питона?